# Error changing creation date on my mp4 files

Tags: powershell

I've used this code to from a previous answer to change the creation date on my mp4's but just get errors when I enter a date:

```
$movFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Neil\Pictures\Fishing" -Filter *.MP4

Foreach ($file in $movFiles) 
{
   $fileName = $file.Name 

   $userDate = Read-Host -Prompt "Date wanted for ${fileName} (format--> 13-02-1970) "
   $newDateObj = Get-Date -Date userDate 
   $file.CreationTime = $newDateObj
}
```

Date wanted for "429V Set up Steps  swim 27th Aug 2011 Red Water.mp4" (format--> 13-02-1970): **27-08-2011**.  I enter the date but get this error:

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "userDate" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "The string
was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."
At line:5 char:30
+ $newDateObj = Get-Date -Date userDate $file.CreationTime = $newDateOb ...
+                              ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

Comment: You are missing a `$` from `userDate`: `$newDateObj = Get-Date -Date userDate $file.CreationTime = $newDateObj`

Comment: That line will still throw an error though

Comment: I hesitated to edit the formatting this question because of the coding errors I saw. There was an errant double quote in the original code that was removed with the last edit. I cannot trust this is how the OP is working with their code either.

Comment: There's a newline missing from the code (after `$userDate` on the last line of the `foreach` statement).